# SQL and search in many column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

My sql in rails

```
@search = @search.where('txt_1 OR txt_2 OR keywords like ?', some_value)
```

Why this doesn't work. When I have only " txt_1 OR txt_2 " - i think it works ok. But when I add next OR, there is no result when some_value doesn't exist in last OR.

ANSWER:

ok as I see, OR is condition that return true for one OR/AND second variable. I make this like that, and it works - I don't know is this a good solution

```
 @items.where(' (txt_1 OR txt_2  like ?) OR (keywords like ?) ', "%#{search_name}%","%#{search_name}%")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `OR` statement in SQL has to be used to compare different assertion, like `something = 'something' OR other_thing = 'other_stuff'`.

In your case, you should use the `OR` keyword as the following:

```
@items.where('txt_1 LIKE ? OR txt_2 LIKE ? OR keywords LIKE ?', "%#{search_name}%","%#{search_name}%", "%#{search_name}%")
```

But since you use the same value (`search_name`), you can use this pretty usefull syntax:

```
@items.where('txt_1 LIKE :search OR txt_2 LIKE :search OR keywords LIKE :search', search: "%#{search_name}%")
```